# How do you use reDoc with multiple files

Tags: openapi, redoc

My API documentation is getting quite large and I was wondering if it was possible to separate the `openapi.yml` file into separately managed chunks rather than having it all in one and have reDoc (or some other tool) combine it and then generate the HTML site.

Answer (score 1):

Redoc has its own tool for that "Redoc CLI" [npm @redocly/cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@redocly/cli)

checkout their tutorial https://github.com/Redocly/openapi-starter

with this tool you can:

1. split your actual docs with one command
   (to paths, components, parameters, schema)

```
redocly split openapi.yaml --outDir openapi
```

2. lint them (separated files or final one)

```
redocly lint openapi/openapi.yaml
```

3. preview (with hot reloading on change)

```
redocly preview-docs openapi/openapi.yaml
```

4. and merge them back when production ready

```
redocly bundle openapi/openapi.yaml -o openapi.yaml
```

and even more...